# how do you add an attibute to root element of XML DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

i created a XML document using **DOMDocument** and simpleXML. I need to add an attibute to the root element.

Below is how I created the document and the element. You will note that although the document is initally created by DOMDocument, the child/user nodes are created with simple XML.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');

    /*** create the root element ***/ 
    $root = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement( "Feed" )); 


    /*** create the simple xml element ***/ 
    $sxe = simplexml_import_dom( $dom ); 

    /*** add a user node ***/ 
    $firstChild = $sxe->addchild("FirstChild");
```

I tried adding the attibutes to the root like this:

> $root = $dom->appendData($dom->createAttribute("extractDate",
>   "$now"));

but this does not work.

Comment: Why should have `DOMDocument::appendData()` (a method that doesn't even exist) worked? And which error and return value were you getting? You're hiding this important information from your question. Perhaps you were just getting an error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Using **`DOMDocument`**, you can set the attribute using the [`DOMElement::setAttribute`](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php) method:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
$root = $dom->createElement("Feed");  
$attr = $root->setAttribute("extractDate", "$now"); // <-- here

$dom->appendChild($root);
```

For **`SimpleXML`**, you'll need to use the [`SimpleXMLElement::addAttribute`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addattribute.php) method:

```
$sxe = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
$sxe->addAttribute("extractDate", "$now"); // <-- here
```

Comment: Thank you Robby. that is perfect